# Как проверить правильность записи целого числа в восьмеричной системе счисления

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

Программа должна вывести ответ 'YES', если строка представляет собой правильную запись целого числа в восьмеричной системе счисления, и 'NO', если запись ошибочна.

```
a = int(input())
if ' %s ' %  oct(a) == 'TRUE':
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: Станислав, добавила попытку решить задачу

Comment: o_O И что же ЭТОТ код должен сделать? какая идея в него вложена? почему Вы полагаете, что он решит поставленную задачу? Кстати, а что вообще в данном случае "правильная запись целого числа в восьмеричной системе счисления"?

Comment: ' %s ' %  oct(a) должен перевести число в восьмеричную систему счисления, а дальше я не знаю какая должна быть логика проверки, поэтому задала вопрос

Comment: @Yana Так у вас обратная задача - дана строка в восьмеричной системе (или нет).

Comment: А как исключить число, где 0 на первом месте? 012335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто указать для `int` восьмеричную систему счисления. Если не упадёт - значит всё нормально.

```
x = input()
try:
    y = int(x, 8)
    print('YES')
except ValueError:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Как не стыдно показывать начинающим программистам `except:` без типа исключения. Ай-Ай-Ай!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ок, мне очень стыдно! )

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите проверить что на входе восьмеричное целое со знаком, можно проверить что функция `int(x, 8)` не приводит к ошибке:

```
x = input()

is_oct = True
try:
    int(x, 8)
except ValueError:
    is_oct = False

if is_oct:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

> ```
> $ echo 67 | python is_oct.py
> YES
>
> $ echo 68 | python is_oct.py
> NO
>
> $ echo -67 | python is_oct.py
> YES
>
> $ echo -68 | python is_oct.py
> NO
> ```

Помимо знака в начале числа этот способ разрешает подчёркивания и префикс `'0o'` ([Integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers)):

> ```
> $ echo 10_000 | python is_oct.py
> YES
>
> $ echo 0o67 | python is_oct.py
> YES
> ```

Если вам не нравятся эти (довольно странные) дополнения к восьмеричным числам, надо проверять цифры вручную. Во-первых, надо убедиться что строка не пустая. Во-вторых, проверить что каждый символ - восьмеричная цифра:

```
octs = set('01234567')

x = input()

is_oct = len(x) > 0 and all(d in octs for d in x)

if is_oct:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Те же идеи в другом изложении. Из символов строки `x` строим множество, проверяем что оно подмножество восьмеричных цифр:

```
octs = set('01234567')

x = input()

is_oct = len(x) > 0 and set(x) <= octs

if is_oct:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Не боитесь регулярных выражений? Тогда так:

```
import re


x = input()

is_oct = re.match('^[0-7]+$', x) is not None

if is_oct:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```